# how to hide keyboard in flutter dropdownMenu?

Tags: flutter, material-ui, drop-down-menu

I am using flutter in my propjet, so I have a problem with opening keyboard on flutter DropDownMenu,
I seeking for a way to preventing of opining the keyboard when the user clicked on dropdownMenu list.

I try a lot of way, but all ways never worked for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `requestFocusOnTap: false,`

Example:

```dart
DropdownMenu(
  dropdownMenuEntries: yourDropdownEntries,
  requestFocusOnTap: false,
),
```

[Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownMenu/requestFocusOnTap.html):

> Determine if the dropdown button requests focus and the on-screen virtual keyboard is shown in response to a touch event. [...]

Comment: I don't see this option in `DropdownMenu`

Answer (score 1):

We need to use `enableSearch` as `false` and call `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` when we `onSelected` to hide keyboard

```
DropdownMenu<String>(
      initialSelection: AppConstants.tests.first,
      enableSearch: false,
      onSelected: (String? value) {
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      },
```

Comment: That does not hide the keyboard. Setting `requestFocusOnTap` to `false` does.

Comment: @Ontkibbeling Actually, `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` is hiding the keyboard here along with `enableSearch` as `false`

Answer (score 0):

You can set autofocus property of TextField to false (default)

```
autofocus: false,
```

or call

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

before showing the dropdownMenu

Comment: how can it? can you explain me.